# Conditionally Call Constructor in C#

Tags: c#, constructor, conditional-statements

Let's say I have the following constructors for `Foo` in C#:

```
public Foo()
{
    // ...
}
protected Foo(bool connect)
    : this()
{
    // ...
}
```

I am searching for a way to only execute the `this()` part whenever the `connect` parameter is `true`. Is these a way to do this?

(For curious people: The reasoning behind this is that the `Foo` class creates objects that connect to certain things; when they are created, they should always try to connect as well. Right now, I am creating an emulator (or MOCK) for it which extends the `Foo` class. That's what I'm adding the `protected` constructor for; when this one is used, there should be the option to not create an actual connection. I want to implement this while changing the `Foo` class as little as possible.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot call `this()` conditionally in that way. However, you can move the conditional code to the `protected` contructor and just call that constructor from the `public` one:

```
public Foo() : this(true)
{

}

protected Foo(bool connect)
{
   if(connect) //...
}
```

Comment: I personally favour this approach. It avoids a drawback of calling a non-constructor method which is that `readonly` fields cannot be initialised in a non-constructor. It also scales to many constructors (all of which can call a protected or even private "master" constructor) - although calling an init() method does also scale.

Comment: Yeah, actually I think this is the best way too

Comment: Considering what @MatthewWatson said, this is indeed probably the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

One way to do it, is to create an `init()` function:

```
public Foo()
{
    // ...
    init();
}
protected Foo(bool connect)
{
    // ...
    if (connect) {
        init();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the best way to do it indeed. With `init()` being private, the class won't have visibly changed, which is exactly what I needed.

Comment: This approach doesn't work with `readonly` or `init` (C# 9) members btw.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call this() conditionally so you have to use a method instead

```
public Foo()
{
    ConnectCode();
}
protected Foo(bool connect)
    : this()
{
    if(connect)
        ConnectCode();
}
```

Another way(don't know if it's good or if it is ok for your needs) is:

```
public Foo(bool connect=true)
{
    if(connect)
        ConnectCode();
}
```

This way the code that call Foo() don't need to be changed but you lose the protected accessibility