# Call different constructors of the base class conditionally

Tags: c#, generics, constructor, radix

I have a generic class derived from `HashSet<T>` and I need to initialize the base class with different constructors based on the type of the generic parameter `T`. Something like this:

```
class Set<T> : HashSet<T>
{
    Set()
    {
        if (typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(HashSet<>))
            base = new HashSet<T>(new HashSetComparer<T>());
        else
            base = new HashSet<T>();
    }
}
```

Clearly this code doesn't work. How can I fix it? How can I call different constructors based on the type of `T`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally Call Constructor in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768179/conditionally-call-constructor-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @GSerg That thread has nothing to do with the base class...

Answer (score 1):

If it's a `HashSet<T>`, you can actually do this by:

```cs
class Set<T> : HashSet<T>
{
    Set() : base(
        typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(HashSet<>) ? 
        new HashSetComparer<T>() : null)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `base(null)` is the same as `base()`? 

Comment: @MinimusHeximus It is. You can even find `public HashSet() : this((IEqualityComparer<T>?)null) { }` on https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/HashSet.cs,eca9ea30fa3b2c28